# Fit polygons in another polygon

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, alignment

Is there any way to perfectly fit the blue shapes into the green shapes? I have over 7k blue shapes and 550 green shapes and I would love if someone could help me to avoid me doing all the fitting manually.

[image]

I'm using QGIS 3.10.4.

---

EDIT: When i use the "snap geometries to layer" the boundary lines are fine but the inner lines remain in the same place:

[image]

Comment: Menu Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Difference ? See here : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference

Comment: mmm that tool will not fix my problem in the shape's lower parts

Answer (score 2):

You could try running the processing tool "snap geometries to layer". Choose a suiting snap tolerance (in CRS units) and the desired behavior from the dropdown menu. Set your green ones as Input Layer and your blue ones as Reference Layer.

Like this for example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that solve me almost 95% of the work!

Comment: I found a problem! this script doesn't fit the inner lines! only the boundary lines

Comment: What should happen to the inner lines? Can you draw an example of the expected output?

Comment: When i use the "snap geometries to layer" the boundary lines are fine but the inner lines remain in the same place
https://i.imgur.com/Sykw7EP.png

Comment: I see. Dont know of an out of the box solution for this. Maybe someone else does, better include this in your question body.